# StartsWith method C# doesn't return TRUE

Tags: c#, string, startswith

I read some values from MS SQL database and I like to make some operations on string. Here is the code I am using to check if some string starts with another string:

```
String input = "Основното jавно обвинителство денеска поднесе пријава против БМ (59) од Битола заради постоење основи на сомнение дека сторил кривични дела „тешки дела против безбедноста на луѓето и имотот во сообраќајот“ и „неукажување помош на лице повредено во сообраќајна незгода“";
String subString = "Основното јавно обвинителство";
if (input.StartsWith(subString))
{
    Response.Write("OK");
}
```

However `input.StartsWith(subString)` does not return true. Does anybody have an idea why?

Comment: As a recomendation; [Best Practices for Using Strings in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465121(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The difference is in the character `j` in the position 10: its code is 106 in the input, but in your substring it's 1112 (`0x458` - see [demo](http://ideone.com/JTwb6I)).

Your second `j` comes from [Unicode page 4](http://pl.wikisource.org/wiki/Unicode/4)

```
ј   1112    458 0xD1 0x98   CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER JE
```

It looks the same, but has a different code.

Re-typing `j` in the `substring` fixes this problem.

Answer (score 10):

The second words in the input and the subString don't match.  Put the strings in notepad++ and select each word at a time.  The first and last word in the subString match but not the middle one.

[This sample](https://ideone.com/2uzuVj) demonstrates the problem:

```
void Main()
{
    var test = "Основното јавно обвинителство";
    var tost = "Основното jавно обвинителство";

    for(var i = 0; i < test.Length; i++){
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("1: {0}, 2: {1}, Equal: {2}", test[i], tost[i], test[i] == tost[i]));
        if(test[i] != tost[i]){ Console.WriteLine (string.Format("1: {0}, 2: {1}", (int) test[i], (int) tost[i])); }
    }

    Console.WriteLine (test == tost);
}
```

Relevant output:

```
1: ј, 2: j, Equal: False
1: 1112, 2: 106
```

Comment: Specifically, in the second word "jавно", the "input" string has a "j" as the first character, in "subString", the first character is "%d1%98".

Answer (score 6):

The strings that you're posted are *not equal*. Do this:

```
string s1 = "Основното јавно обвинителство";
string s2 = "Основното jавно обвинителство";
var bt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s1);
var bt_1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s2);
```

Output will look similar to the following:

```
56
55
```

The actual difference is as follows. The "j" in the first string is:

```
[19]    209 byte
[20]    152 byte
```

whereas the "j" in the second string is:

```
[19]    106 byte
```

First one represents `ј` with [`0xD1 0x98`](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=1024&number=1024&names=-&utf8=0x) hexadecimal code and second one represent `j` with [`0x6A`](http://ss64.com/ascii.html) hexadecimal code.